# ES6 Let Const Block Scope Is Carrying Over Inside For Loop For Some Variables

Tags: javascript, scope, ecmascript-6

I am experiencing some bizarre results when dealing with let and const inside a for loop. I was under the impressions that a variable defined with let or const has a scope limited to the brackets surrounding it.

So in a for loop a new scope would be defined for each let and const. However some of my variables inside the for loop are carrying scope from each iteration. What's weird is that it is not all of the variables inside the for loop.

If it were all of them I would guess that my assumption about how let and const scope worked was wrong. The fact that only some of them are carrying isn't making sense to me.

I am running this in Chrome - Version 60.0.3112.113 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I have cut down some of my code to make it more concise to follow but look for `"// ***"` to see where my variable's scopes aren't making sense.

```
    for (let i = 0; i < combinedRoles.length; i++)
    {
        // *** orgs, permObjArray, roleOrgTree, rolePanelId are all carrying scope
        const orgs = $sidebar.data("org-tree");
        const orgRole = combinedRoles[i];
        const roleId = orgRole.roleId;
        const permObjArray = orgRole.permObjsArray;

        const rolePanelId = "#user-" + user.userId + "-role-" + roleId;
        const $selectedRoleRow = $userPanel.find(".role-selection-row.selected");
        let $roleSelection = $userPanel.find(rolePanelId);
        $roleSelection.data("roleData", orgRole);

        // *** roleOrgTree's scope is carrying over between "i" iterations
        // *** So below when I set the data value for the html element from before. 
        let roleOrgTree = [];
        roleOrgTree = orgs.map(function(org)
        {
            let stateObj = {checked : false, checkbox_disabled : false, selected : false};
            org.a_attr = { "class" : "role-org-tree-anchor" };
            org.li_attr = { "class" : "role-org-tree-li" }
            currUserOrgPerms = org.anmUserRole.permissions;

            if ($.inArray(roleId, org.availableRoleIds) < 0)
            {
                org.a_attr = { "class" : "role-org-tree-anchor disable-org-tree-anchor role-not-available" };
                org.li_attr = { "class" : "role-org-tree-li disable-org-tree-node" }
                stateObj.checkbox_disabled = true;
            }

            org.state = stateObj;
            return org;
        });

        // *** What's happening is since roleOrgTree's scope is carrying over 
        // *** it is changing the previous element's data object
        $roleSelection.data("roleOrgTree", roleOrgTree);

        // *** However the scope is not carrying over for permissionsTree 
        // *** and each html element's data object is correct
        let permissionsTree = [];
        let familyTree = [];
        // Creating the permissions tree for this role
        //permObjArray.forEach(function(obj) {
        permissionsTree = permObjArray.map(function(obj) {
            const permFamily = obj.perm_family;
            if (familyTree.indexOf(permFamily) < 0)
            {
                familyTree.push(permFamily);
                const familyObj = { 
                    id: permFamily, 
                    text : permFamily, 
                    parent : "#", 
                    li_attr: { "class" : "disable-org-tree-node" }, 
                    a_attr : { "class" : "disable-org-tree-anchor hide-checkbox" }
                };
                permissionsTree.push(familyObj);
            }

            obj.state = {checked: true, selected: true, checkbox_disabled : true};
            obj.li_attr = { "class" : "disable-org-tree-node" };
            obj.a_attr = { "class" : "disable-org-tree-anchor" };
            return obj;
        });

        // *** permissionsTree scope is not carrying over so the previous
        // *** element's ($roleSelection) data object is not getting over written
        $roleSelection.data("rolePermTree", permissionsTree);
    };
```

From my chrome developer tools you can see that on the right hand side under "Scope" and Block the variables already have a scope but are just undefined. Why would that be?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It's hard to understand the problem the way you've described it. Can you add the HTML and explain what it's supposed to do and what it's doing instead?

Comment: You're modifying the `org` objects that are saved in `$sidebar.data("org-tree")`.

Comment: It's supposed to be copying a template html div and for each role that a user might has. So it will create a clone of the template and place it into the DOM and then store a few objects inside the data object of the cloned template for access later on.

Comment: @Barmar, the map function doesn't create a new instance? And if that were the case why wouldn't permissionsTree be carrying scope as well

Comment: The `map` function creates a new array, but the elements of the array are references to the `org` objects that came from the `orgs` array. And you're modifying those objects in place with `org.a_attr = ...`

Comment: This doesn't look like a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$sidebar.data("org-tree")` doesn't make a clone of the data, it simply returns a reference to it. So when you later map over the `orgs` and do:

```
org.a_attr = ...;
org.li_attr = ...;
```

you're modifying the objects that are in the element's data, and that affects the next iteration of the loop.

You should clone these objects before modifying them.

```
    roleOrgTree = orgs.map(function(org)
    {
        org = Object.assign({}, org);
        let stateObj = {checked : false, checkbox_disabled : false, selected : false};
        org.a_attr = { "class" : "role-org-tree-anchor" };
        org.li_attr = { "class" : "role-org-tree-li" }
        currUserOrgPerms = org.anmUserRole.permissions;

        if ($.inArray(roleId, org.availableRoleIds) < 0)
        {
            org.a_attr = { "class" : "role-org-tree-anchor disable-org-tree-anchor role-not-available" };
            org.li_attr = { "class" : "role-org-tree-li disable-org-tree-node" }
            stateObj.checkbox_disabled = true;
        }

        org.state = stateObj;
        return org;
    });
```

BTW, there's no point in initializing `roleOrgTree = []` if you're immediately going to reassign it from `orgs.map()`.

Comment: the initialization of roleOrgTree was desperation, I couldn't figure out what was causing the scope to carry and was trying anything.

Comment: This worked, and I had initially just made a new instance of roleOrgTree right after mapping and that worked as well but I couldn't figure out why scope would carry. Event still with this when I pause the debugger at the first line in the for loop, roleOrgTree is still defined on the next iteration. Am I missing something still?

Comment: That seems to be a debugger artifact. If you try to access the variable in code, it will be undefined.